# How to fix the pacman command to allow me to register my microcode on Linux

Tags: linux, pacman

just finished installing Arch Linux on my computer to the point where I can boot my system without
the thumb drive.  After rebooting, I started making some adjustments and quickly realized that my paceman
command no longer works correctly and I am not sure why.  At first I though that I might not be connected
to the internet anymore but I ran several successful pin commands that indicate I am still connected
to the internet.  For example, if I try to install the microcode for my intel processor I get the following
errors.  I am only showing a few of the errors, but it appears that it has tried every site on my mirror
list and failed them all.  I typed the following input.

```
sudo pacman -S intel-ucode
```

which provided the initial following output.

```
resolving dependencies
looking for conflicting packages…

packages (1) intel-code-20210216-1

total Download Size: 2.67 MiB
total Installed Size: 3.46 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n]
```

I press enter to accept the default of yes and I get the following errors.  Again this only shows the errors
for some of the sites, but it appears it is running through all the sites on the mirror list.

```
error: failed retrieving file ‘intel-code-20210216-1-any.pkg.tar.zst’ from www.caco.ic.unicap.br : Could not resolve host: www.caco.ic.unicamp.br
error: failed retrieving file ‘intel-code-20210216-1-any.pkg.tar.zst’ from ftp.agdsn.de : Could not resolve host: ftp.agdsn.de
error: failed retrieving file ‘intel-code-20210216-1-any.pkg.tar.zst’ from mirror.darklinux.uk : Could not resolve host: mirror.darklinux.uk
error: failed retrieving file ‘intel-code-20210216-1-any.pkg.tar.zst’ from mirror.surf : Could not resolve host: mirror.surf.  
warning: failed to retrieve some files
error: failed to commit transaction (invalid url for server)
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded
```

It is clear that my internet is working and that it is querying the mirror sites, which indicates to me that there is something wrong with my pacman command.  Any help that someone could give me would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem should lie with your nameserver configuration.

```
Could not resolve host: www.caco.ic.unicamp.br
```

You have internet connection, but either the DNS that you have connected to has no access to other DNS services, or it has no internet connection itself (or the configuration itself is invalid).

Try setting the following in `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

This will tell your machine to ask Google's DNS for domain name resolution.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work either.  I still get the same errors!